# Fork System call in linux using c

Tags: c

What if I'm writing this??
I got both of the printf statements executed!!

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    if(fork())
        printf("entering IF");
    else
        printf("entering ELSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly as expected. Were you expecting something else?

Comment: yes,   actually I got op like this....   ubuntu@ubuntu_VM : IN IF not followed by IN ELSE

Comment: but a new fresh line ubuntu@ubuntu_VM: IN ELSE !! followed by the previous line

Comment: Though, parent and child process may run _concurrently_ (parallel), they share one console output. Hence, one of the two processes "may win" and output first. Which one is not defined.

Comment: I thought this was a duplicate, but I can't find canonical answer to this question. Strange.

Comment: You cannot expect a new fresh line. For starters, neither of your `if` branches output a newline, so where should it come from?

Comment: Don't know who voted up. I consider this question as a bit unclear. @AnushaVerma Could you [edit] the question and describe in more detail what exactly you do not understand? (Often it helps to describe "output you got" vs. "expected output".)

Comment: At any rate, you should (1) post the output as text rather than image (2) post your *expexted* output in the same way. You can [edit] your question and fix these issues.

Comment: If you want processes to execute certain statements in a specific order then you must synchronise them in some way, usually using some form of InterProcess Communication (IPC).

Answer (score 3):

What exactly are you asking?
`fork()` duplicates the calling process, returning the child process' PID in the parent, and 0 in the child.

In C, `if` evaluates any non-zero value to true, meaning `entering IF` will be printed from the parent thread, and `entering ELSE` from the child thread.

It should be noted that order in which they are printed is nondeterministic, so you may see `entering ELSE` before `entering IF`.

See: [man(2) fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)

Comment: I found a `.edu` web site with nice illustrations: [The fork() System Call](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html)

Comment: can't I get entering IF instantly followed by entering ELSE ?? without a fresh new tagline of ubuntu

Comment: Well, for starters `printf` does not create a new line, so as it is you'll always get your results on the same line, regardless of what order they end up being executed in.

That being said, you could have the parent process wait for the child process to terminate, but that still won't solve the problem of ordering, only where the new line in your terminal is.

Answer (score 0):

The `fork` system call return value as per manual pages is

> Return Value
>
> > On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is 
> > returned in the child. On failure, -1 is returned in the parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

So, the `if` statement is executed by the `parent` process and where as the `else` is executed by the `child` process.

Answer (score 0):

The `fork()` creates a child process by duplicating the calling process. The process that invokes `fork()` is the **parent process** and the newly created process is the **child process**. So `fork()` splits a process in two, and returns `0` to the child process and the PID of the child process to the parent process, or `-1` if the fork failed.

In the context of your program:

```
if(fork())
    printf("entering IF"); 
else
    printf("entering ELSE");
```

the parent process will print `entering IF` and child process will print `entering ELSE`.

The child process and the parent process run separately. So, you cannot determine which process gets schedules first but there are ways to synchronize them. For e.g. make parent process wait until child finishes, check [**this**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html).

---

**Additional**:

Linux kernel (2.6.23 and later) provides a tunable paramter - `sched_child_runs_first`.
From [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html):

> /proc/sys/kernel/sched_child_runs_first (since Linux 2.6.23)
>                 If this file contains the value zero, then, after a fork(2),
>                 the parent is first scheduled on the CPU.  If the file con‐
>                 tains a nonzero value, then the child is scheduled first on
>                 the CPU.  (Of course, on a multiprocessor system, the parent
>                 and the child might both immediately be scheduled on a CPU.)